# How do I download VirtualBox on Lubuntu 13.10?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I want to download Oracle's VirtualBox on my Lubuntu machine. They don't have any downloads for Lubuntu on their website. So how do I download it on Lubuntu?

Comment: you can get it from software center

Comment: is there an apt-get command for installing it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214111/how-to-install-virtualbox-to-use-windows-or-other-os

Comment: That's ubuntu though. I am using Lubuntu 13.10. I wanted to know whether that works on Lubuntu.

Comment: Lubuntu is Ubuntu with different GUI and different default programs.

Comment: The Oracle version can be installed from their repository replacing distribution with `saucy` as shown here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack this will also work on Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fischer is correct, running:

```
    sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Will install VirtualBox on Lubuntu as well. They are actually pulling from the same repositories.

If you ever want to search for a specific package -- and would prefer not to use the Software Center GUI -- you can use:

```
    apt-cache search <what_you_are_looking_for>
```