# How do I install the latest version of VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) LTS?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I installed [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) through `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`, but it's not working for the installation of [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

When I try to install Genymotion, it says 'no virtual box detected'.

Comment: See [@hg8 answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/685523/439451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to install virtualbox using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

Try this instead.

1. Open Terminal  -> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Type `sudo -i` and enter your password press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type  `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`  <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Scroll down to last and add the following

   ```
   #######VirtualBox Repositories
   deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib
   ```
5. Save it and close.
6. In terminal:

   ```
   wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   apt-get update
   apt-get install dkms
   sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
   ```

Comment: You should use `add-apt-repository 'deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib'` instead of manually editing `sources.list`.

Answer (score 3):

From [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads):

To install the latest virtualbox, first remove the previous versions of Virtualbox by typing the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox*
```

Then, add source:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib"
```

Add the key:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then, to install do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```