# Not able to install Virtual box in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualbox, dpkg

I followed [this Ask Ubuntu guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713823/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr), I manually downloaded virtual box from [this link](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.16/virtualbox-5.0_5.0.16-105871~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb) and tried to install like:

```
$ dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.16-105871~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb
```

But no success, I got this error:

```
    dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.0
```

I got the Oracle Virtual box icon in applications, when i click, it does not open, so geny motion does not recognize any virtual box, so it could not start as well.

Please help me. I have already used

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox*
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib"
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

No success. What am I doing wrong?

- Ubuntu 15.04
- Java version javac 1.8.0_74

Comment: Look at your add-apt-repository.  You're using trusty repositories instead of vivid repositories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Ubuntu 15.04 is not supported anymore, you can install VirtualBox this way :

First completely remove all traces from the previous VirtualBox installation attempts.

```
sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"
```

Download and register the ORACLE public key.

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the VirtualBox repository to the sources.

```
echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
```

Update the repositories :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install VirtualBox 5.0 :

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.0
```

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 15.04 :**

You have to replace `vivid` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !

Comment: then,  how can i install virtual box on my ubuntu 15.04 , can i have try with Ubuntu 15.10 ("Wily") i386 for my 64 bit ??

Comment: @AmulBhatia : Install VirtualBox in Ubuntu 15.04 exactly as described in the answer - of course Ubuntu 15.04 has to be installed in the 64 bit version when you want to use virtualization technology at all ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Download the `.deb` file from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and then run

`sudo dpkg -i <downloaded_file_name>`

That should fix your issues

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for AMD package.

1. Type `uname -a` in command line.
   OUTPUT:
   `Linux christopher 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:31:42 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`
2. I know AMD is not the one.
3. Go to [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) and select the i386 version
4. Download and install

Comment: No you are right see this:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/691216/no-version-of-ubuntu-can-be-installed-with-any-skylake-6th-generation-intel-proc