# Unable to launch VirtualBox in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, kernel, virtualbox, architecture

Attempting to launch VirtualBox in Ubuntu 16.04 produces an error about the `vboxdrv` module not being able to load, then another error about `/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox` not being found.

```
$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.10.0-35-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
/usr/bin/virtualbox: 111: exec: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox: not found
```

To obtain VirtualBox, I downloaded the .deb file from the website and installed it from local using:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox5.1_5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial_i386.deb
```

Comment: Please run this `sudo lsmod | grep vbox` and post into your question

Comment: Is this a fresh install, if so ho did you install, if not what did you do before this issue?

Comment: Actually i downloaded the .deb file from the website and installed it from local using   sudo dpkg -i virtualbox5.1_5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial_i386.deb

Comment: You are using a `32bit` version on a `64bit` Ubuntu ( I am guessing ), please download the `64bit` version

Comment: You will also need to install the `dkms` package which helps you in building the required VirtualBox drivers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install VirtualBox to use Windows or other OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214111/how-to-install-virtualbox-to-use-windows-or-other-os)

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same problem on ubuntu 17.04 amd64 with kernel 4.10.0-35-generic. FIxed with the following line:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

apt installed then libqt5x11extras5. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

From information originally provided in comments, it appears your system is a 64-bit system and you're using a 32-bit VirtualBox installer. Please re-download the 64-bit version for your Ubuntu system.