# Unable to install Virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I tried installing Virtualbox in Ubuntu 16.04 with the command `sudo apt install virtualbox-5.1` but it gives the following error.

```
$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
        available for the current kernel (4.4.0-171-generic) or it failed to
        load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

          sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

        You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
VirtualBox: Error -610 in supR3HardenedMainInitRuntime!
VirtualBox: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxRT.so",) failed: <NULL>

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.
```

I tried solving the error from multiple sites but still no avail.

- [Install Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779095/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)
- [Install Virtualbox on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779095/install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)
- [Unable to launch VirtualBox in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957979/unable-to-launch-virtualbox-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: did you run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` on the terminal? What was the output?

Comment: Are you using secure boot? If so you may have to sign the VBox driver with your MOK or disable secure boot. See [here](https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/)

Comment: When I ran ```sudo /sbin/vboxconfig``` this is what I got:
```vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
```

Comment: Okay, post the contents of `/var/log/vbox-install.log` and I will have a look. You can paste them on https://paste.ubuntu.com and share the link here.

Comment: Okay @Parto done so here: <https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/t7bM4sgKGH/>. Thanks for your response!