# How to install VM box in ubuntu16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, virtualbox

How to install Virtual box in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: By "VM Box" do you mean VirtualBox? If so, https://askubuntu.com/q/214111/521305 shows you how to install it.

Comment: check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367248/how-to-install-virtualbox-from-command-line ........... or you can just install it from software center...

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-virtualbox-version-from-oracle-to-install-an-extension-pack the open source version from the repositories installs with `sudo apt install virtualbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Install Oracle Virtualbox:

Step 1:
Open your favorite editor (nano in my case) and create the file (virutalbox.list) to add repository as:

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list`

Add the following and save the file

2. `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib`

Step 2:
Download and add the key

1. `wget https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc`
2. `sudo apt-key add oracle_vbox_2016.asc`

Step 3:
Update software sources (as usual)

1. `sudo apt-get update`

Step 4:
Finally, Install Virtualbox (current version is 5.1)

1. `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-5.1`

**Finally:**

To run Virtualbox Open Dash (press SUPER key) and type something like "virtual" then click on Oracle VM VirtualBox icon.